# Getting data using 4 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
trendingtopic
  id
  name

trendingtopiccycle
  id
  trendingtopic_id(FK)

tweet
  id 
  text
  tt_cycle_id(FK)
  user_id(FK)

user
  id
  rank
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to retrieve the tweet made from the higher ranked user of each trending topic in an efficient way.

Here's my current query:

```
  SELECT tt."name",
  MAX(tu."actual_rank") AS rank,tu."name"
  FROM "trendingtopics_twitteruser" tu
  LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_tweet" tw ON tu."id" = tw."user_id" 
  LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_trendingtopiccycle" ttc ON tw."tt_cycle_id" = ttc."id"
  LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_trendingtopic" tt ON ttc."tt_id" = tt."id" 
  GROUP BY tt."name"
```

It's not working because, according to Postgresql:' "tu.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function'.

If I add tu."name" to the GROUP BY clause, I end up getting something like this:

```
"106 & Park";0;"910Prince"
"106 & Park";0;"ActressAlexiss"
"106 & Park";0;"AmeliaThirlwall"
"106 & Park";0;"_ArielIvy"
"106 & Park";0;"_AyyeVce"
"106 & Park";0;"barcastuff"
"106 & Park";0.42141;"pareexo"
"106 & Park";0.0363;"khleosupporters"
"#15ThingsAboutMyCrush";0;"_ALoyalLady"
"#15ThingsAboutMyCrush";0.22275;"AmberrNikole"
"#15ThingsAboutMyCrush";0;"a_paigeturner"
"#15ThingsAboutMyCrush";0.33942018;"ArleneAndrea_xo"
```

But what I want to get is:

```
"106 & Park";0.42141;"pareexo"
"#15ThingsAboutMyCrush";0.33942018;"ArleneAndrea_xo"
```

Comment: @mfalcom: Thats the  basic of sql ,the non aggregate column should be in group by clause,so you must add `tu.name` in the group by clause.

Comment: Gaurav, I've updated the post with more information.

Comment: Which version of Postgresql are you using?

Comment: Oh, and if you want to contact somebody put @ sign in front of his/hers name.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: I'm using 9.1 version.

Comment: Then @spfiredrake's answer will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this can easily be done using window functions in a subquery:

```
SELECT t."topic_name", t."rank", t."user_name"
FROM 
    (SELECT tt."name" AS topic_name, tu."actual_rank" AS rank, tu."name" AS user_name,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY tt."name" ORDER BY tu."actual_rank" DESC) user_rank
    FROM "trendingtopics_trendingtopic" tt
    LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_trendingtopiccycle" ttc ON ttc."tt_id" = tt."id"
    LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_tweet" tw ON tw."tt_cycle_id" = ttc."id"
    LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_twitteruser" tu ON tu."id" = tw."user_id") t
WHERE t."user_rank" = 1
```

Also, I reordered the joins so that you START with the trending topic instead of the twitter user. Since you're trying to get the highest ranked user for the trending topic, makes more sense (to me at least) to start with that as the source table.

For more information regarding window functions and partitioning, go here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: I tried the query but I get a syntax error near tu: FROM "trendingtopics_trendingtopic" tt tu

Comment: There was an artifact from when I was rearranging the join order. Give it a try now.

Comment: Now I get this error: column "tu.actual_rank" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: Grouping wasn't necessary, again an artifact from copy/pasta. Give it one more try.

Comment: Thank you SPFiredrake for your help, It's working great!. I'll read the link to fully understand the query.

Answer (score 1):

The *fastest* solution is probably to use `DISTINCT ON` rather than a window function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (tt."name")
    tt."name", tu."actual_rank" AS rank, tu."name"
  FROM "trendingtopics_twitteruser" tu
  LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_tweet" tw ON tu."id" = tw."user_id" 
  LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_trendingtopiccycle" ttc ON tw."tt_cycle_id" = ttc."id"
  LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_trendingtopic" tt ON ttc."tt_id" = tt."id" 
  ORDER BY tt."name", tu."actual_rank" DESC;
```

By the way, this is untested because you didn't provide statements to actually create and load the tables you described.  If you *do* provide that sort of thing in the question, people will normally test their answers before posting, and you won't have silly errors to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tt."name",
  MAX(tu."actual_rank") AS rank,MAX(tu."name") as name_1
  FROM "trendingtopics_twitteruser" tu
  LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_tweet" tw ON tu."id" = tw."user_id" 
  LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_trendingtopiccycle" ttc ON tw."tt_cycle_id" = ttc."id"
  LEFT JOIN "trendingtopics_trendingtopic" tt ON ttc."tt_id" = tt."id" 
  GROUP BY tt."name"
```

Comment: This works by accident only. OP wants `tu.Name` from the same row(s) containing `max(tu.Actual_Rank)`.